# How To Add A Ruby Blog to a Rails 3 App

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sinatra

Is it possible to add a blog system like toto ou jekyll to an existing Rails 3 app?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as the blog is a Rack app, you can mount it in the router. See Yehuda Katz' [excellent post](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/12/26/the-rails-3-router-rack-it-up/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this stakoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596233/can-a-rails-app-and-a-jekyll-blog-live-together) and [jekyll-admin project](https://github.com/zkarpinski/Jekyll-Admin/blob/master/README)

Answer (score 0):

Yup, [Toto](http://github.com/cloudhead/toto) and [RubySlippers](http://ruby-slippers.heroku.com) I know can be integrated into a Rails 3 app.

If you want a nice, hackable pure ruby & rack blog:

It uses git to manage versioning of your posts and publishing as well. It is built to get a free blog going on heroku in record time!

`gem install ruby-slippers-engine`

- Template system (by separating business and presentation)
- Ruby 1.8 and 1.9
- Fully tested with [Riot](http://github.com/cloudhead/toto), protest the slow test!
- Includes comments via discus, tagging, markdown, archives and more

~ note: I am the author of RubySlippers and a contributor to Toto